# How to change timeout in Pyserial?

Tags: python, timeout, pyserial

How to change timeout in Pyserial after initialize serial?
Like:
`ser=serial.Serial("COM4", baudrate=19200,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,timeout=0.5)`
After that, I want to change timeout.
Any examples?
Thanks
B.R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the docs (https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.timeout) it seems as though you should simply have to set the attribute on the object:

```py
ser.timeout = 1.0
```